# Actual padding of a Button

Tags: android, xml

I want to know what is the actual padding of android **Button**
I know its not a padding but a shadow, but I need to make pixel perfect layout and take this space into consideration.
Lets look at the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/someButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/someButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/someButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/someButton"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />


    <Button
        android:text="someButton"
        android:id="@+id/someButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, as you can see, top and bottom paddings are the same, but they do not equal to side paddings. What are the exact values of this paddings?
Thanks

[image: button]

Comment: https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html

Comment: try using guidelines in constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Try using guidelines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<View
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/someButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/someButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/someButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/someButton"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />


<Button
    android:text="someButton"
    android:id="@+id/someButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
    // same for top and bottom constraints
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />

                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

// for top and bottom create top, bottom guideline with orientation set to horizontal (0.10, and 0.90 means 10% spacing from left and 10% spacing from right. You can change it to your liking). Also set button's width to "0dp"